# How to toggle between Pointer and Link in the flow editors of Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

In in the grapthical **flow editors** of Blue Prism **ProcessStudio** and **ObjectStudio**, you permanently need to

- move or modify items using the **Pointer** tool
- connect items using the **Link** tool

Is there a **faster way to activate those tools** then selecting them from the left pane with all the available tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- move or modify items using the Pointer tool - hit F2
- connect items    using the Link tool - hit F3